# "For" loop with meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor, iron-router

I'm new to meteor, my question is like this. I want to make a select with option lists like:

```
 <ul id="collapseFour" class="collapse">                        
    <select id="uhd">                            
       {{#each uhdNum}}
          <option>{{number}}</option>
       {{/each}}
    </select>                        
 </ul>
```

I know that I can do it by helpers, but I don't know how to do it. Instead of number there must be 1,2,3,4 up to 50. I created helper file

```
UHDResults = new Meteor.Collection('uhdResults');
Template.adminLayout.helpers({
  uhdNum: function() {
  var number;
  for(var i=0;i<49;i++){
    number[i] = i;
  }
  return number;
}  
});
```

But there are no effect. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `#each` block, replace `<option>{{number}}</option>` with `<option>{{this}}</option>`.

In your js file, number should be defined as an array like so:

```
var number = [];
```

Everything else should work. If there is still problems, replace:

```
number[i] = i;
```

with

```
number.push(i);
```